# Node Express Content-Length

Tags: node.js, express, content-length

I use node.js and express at a small project. I set response header like blow:

```
res.set({'Content-Type':'text/plain;charset=utf-8',    
'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data, 'utf-8')});
```

I can use `console.log` print data's length is 317.

But at browser's console, I just get these:

> Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Encoding:gzip
>   Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8
>   Date:Sat, 01 Jun 2013 08:21:59 GMT
>   Transfer-Encoding:chunked
>   Vary:Accept-Encoding
>   X-Powered-By:Express

So, why the ***content-length*** disappeared?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The response has `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. Here `Content-Length` is not applicable, because the content is sent in one or more parts (chunks) inside the response body, with a marker indicating the byte-length of each individual chunk. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Node.js defaults to `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. However, this is disabled by setting the `Content-Length` header on the native http response object. [Documentation of HTTP module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) says:

> Sending a 'Content-length' header will disable the default chunked encoding.

Going by the `Content-Encoding:gzip` header in your response, you probably have enabled the `connect.compress` middleware. The `connect.compress` middleware removes the `Content-Length` header.

In any case, unless you are generating gzipped content yourself, the `Content-Length` header you generate yourself would surely be inappropriate for the final (gzipped) response body. Luckily, the connect middleware takes care of that for you.

When using Express or Connect, you should not assume that the things you "send" with the res object actually get sent that way to the client. There's middleware in between. All middleware has the ability to change just about anything about the response, including changing the response body, and adding, removing and changing headers. Same goes for the request.

See also these questions:

- [Chunked encoding and content-length header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304126/chunked-encoding-and-content-length-header)
- [HTTP Chunked data size and content length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929484/http-chunked-data-size-and-content-length)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know who did this downvote, but you're right. Thank you very much. After comment `app.use(express.compress());`, content-length appears. But, can I use gzip and content-length both?

Comment: @DMDGeeker, in principle, yes, you can use `Transfer-Encoding: gzip` and `Content-Length` together. However, not with the `express.compress` middleware. It just doesn't support that. In principle, sending a Content-Length header is to be preferred if you can know the response length. You could compress content yourself or look for different "compression" middleware. But `Content-Length` must reflect the actual content sent. It must reflect the byte-length of the final (perhaps compressed) body.

Comment: The reason `connect.compress` does not add a new `Content-Length` to the response is that it would require buffering the compressed response body. Only when the buffer is complete can the content-length  be known, after all.

Comment: If you gzip the buffer yourself using `zlib.gzip` and then do `res.set ({"Transfer-Encoding": "gzip"})`, the `connect.compress` middleware won't touch it.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a try.