# How can i remove the content-length header field in a request?

Tags: node.js, express, request

I'm using express js 4.0 and the [request package](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to make a request to another application in my network.  In my request header, when the `'content-length'` is specified, i'm not able to get a response (i get a "ERRTIMEDOUT").

I tried to remove the 'content-length' field by using the compress middleware. However, even that came to no help, even though according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870904/node-express-content-length), compress should remove it.

As a hack i set `'Transfer-encoding' : 'Chunked'` in my header and I get the response.

Whats the right way to solve this problem? My application configuration is as follows :

```
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || '3000');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

.....
```

I made the same request with the same code in express js 3 and the content-length header was not being added.

Comment: What is the request you are making? What are you expecting in return?

Comment: The Content-Lenght header generating the problem is on the request on your client (e.g. browser) or in the request done by this express app to the external web server?

Comment: @clay - i'm making a request to get some json from another application.

Comment: What kind of request, POST? Can you show us the code of the external request?