# get content-length from request headers, node

Tags: javascript, request-promise

I am making a get request to a web site and want to get `content-length` from response `headers`.

```
import rp from "request-promise";

const options = {
  uri: "http://www.dadaabstories.org/",
  resolveWithFullResponse: true
};

rp(options).then(res => {
  console.log(res.headers);
}).catch(err => {
  throw err;
});
```

The response I am getting is without `content-length`:

> server: 'openresty',
>       date: 'Tue, 05 Mar 2019',
>      'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
>      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
>       connection: 'close',
>       vary: 'Accept-Encoding, X-UA-Device, Accept, Accept-Encoding',
>       'x-rid': 'adbfe4b6b62c7a71bce234e33a6f07f5',
>       p3p: someData',
>     'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
>     'x-content-type-options': 'someData',
>     'x-tumblr-user': 'someData',
>     'x-tumblr-pixel-0': 'someData',
>     'x-tumblr-pixel-2': 'someData',
>     'x-tumblr-pixel': 'someData',
>      link: 'someData',
>     'x-robots-tag': 'noindex, nofollow',
>     'x-ua-compatible': 'someData',
>     'x-ua-device': 'someDevice'

But for this demo web site `http://stack.imgur.com/` I get `content-length`.

I've learned [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870904/node-express-content-length) that `'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'` is disabling `content-length`. So how actually can I get it?

Like how Chrome browser is showing the size. Maybe even it's not `contetn-length` response that I am trying to get.

[image: Chrome dev tool]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a manner of the backend of the website. If the server by default does not include the Content-Length, that it is usually included during the exchange of file, generally there is no possibility in the HTTP protocol to explicitly ask the header that you want.

Comment: The resource that you followed explains how to include the content lenght in the response of a call from the server side. In this case you are not providing a response to a HTTP call but fetching a resource online. Depending on the website you fetch the content length might be included or not.

Comment: Would it be correct if I count it like so? `Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(res);`

Comment: If you are fetching via REST API yes, but generally you have to be sure to retrieve a JSON objects, otherwise don't try to cast it in a object.