# Is there a way to know how large a file being streamed via http is?

Tags: node.js, http, express, stream, content-length

I'm sending a fairly large file via express in a little node app of mine.  As the file is so large, I send the file in a stream.

On the receiving node app that is downloading the file, I would really like the ability to track the progress of the download.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323152/get-download-progress-in-node-js-with-request) uses the 'content-length' header to determine how big a file is.  However after a [little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870904/node-express-content-length) more [research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), it seems that when streaming a file the content-length cannot be known ahead of time.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?  I'm a bit surprised that there is no way to know how big a file being streamed is before it's finished downloading...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “send the file in a stream”? Is it some Node.js feature? HTTP itself doesn’t have a concept of “streaming” — it’s always “streaming” through TCP — it just has two different ways of signaling where a message ends: `Content-Length` (when you know the length in advance) or `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` (when you don’t).

Answer (score 0):

if you upload via multipart/form-data you can find the content-length included.